# How to runtime-check if code is guarded by given asio::strand instance

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I would like to add a runtime assertion to my code that checks if the code is guarded by a given strand.

Here is a pseudo example:

```
...

asio::io_service my_io_service;
asio::strand my_strand(my_io_service);

...

void my_async_callback(void) {
// ASSERT that check that my_strand is guarding then code      
ASSERT(?? my_strand ??)
}

...

// With this call my_async_callback is guarded by strand
my_strand.post(&my_async_callback);
...

// With this call my_async_callback is NOT guarded by strand
io_service.post(&my_async_callback);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for

```
 assert(my_strand.running_in_this_thread());
```

See [the documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5f55%5f0/doc/html/boost%5fasio/reference/io%5fservice%5f%5fstrand/running%5fin%5fthis%5fthread.html)

Comment: Notice that the method running_in_this_thread was added i boost 1.54.0